# How important is the word "Please" when asking for something?

Tags: american-english, british-english, politeness

How important is this word 'please' when asking someone you don't know for something? If you have already said "excuse me" is it still necessary? Is it more important than 'Thank you'? I have heard that it is more important in some places like the UK than in the USA. Also I have heard that it is different with young people. 
Can anybody clarify this to me, *please*?

> "You forgot to say please." Terminator II Judgment Day

Comment: ***Please and thank you***: *Please and thank you are usually associated with politeness. **We use them a lot in English*** .http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/please-and-thank-you

Comment: To add to Josh's answer, and to answer your other question, I would consider "Excuse me" sufficiently polite on its own, but people do add 'please'. "Excuse me, could you please help me find Main Street?". As with most manners or social customs, young people may have a different view. However, I am not that old (22), and have always been careful to use please and thank you when requesting something from anyone. Most of my friends would agree. Please is not more important than thank you, in my opinion - I would consider thanking someone for helping you more important than asking for it politely

Comment: How are you measuring importance? Define *important*. POB.

Comment: Politeness (appropriate language for the situation) is a very important skill to learn when learning any language. This question might be better suited to our sister site, [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

In my experience in the USA using 'please' can come across as overly formal/patronizing in some contexts, and absolutely necessary in others. Take into account the age and general manners of the other person.

One phrase that you can use to avoid sounding patronizing that will typically still be considered polite/respectful:

> Excuse me, could you kindly tell me about your shop?

Intonation is also very important.
Using please, if you sound impatient or angry, will still make a benign request sound more like a command.

Comment: Whereabouts in the US would you hear "could you kindly"?

Comment: You can hear it infrequently in upstate New York, (where I am from) though it's still less common than 'Could you please' or 'Would you please'.